# How do I generate an id for form data input to save the data in an array?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Good day all I have a simple laravel project that takes some information about actors and saves it in a json file after the user fills in the form.My problem is that I save simple data like name, surname, nationality ,age I need a Id something like "edf33e5751b2ea2fd25ad118edbc647e" to save the data in a json file by using arrays.How do I take the user input data from the form add an ID to the data so I can save it to a json file and later use the data by ID?
This is my form where I get my data and send it to my controller to be saved.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('actor.store')}}">
@csrf
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="input">Actor Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Actor Name" name ="name" required="required" minlength="3" maxlegnth="30">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="input">Actor Surname</label>
      <input type="text" required="required" minlength="3" maxlegnth="30" class="form-control" id="actorSurname" placeholder="Actor Surname" name ="surName">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="input">Actor Nationallity</label>
      <select id="nationallity" class="form-control" name ="nationallity" required="required" minlength="3" maxlegnth="30" >
        <option selected>--Select Actor Nationallity.</option>
        <option>South African</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="input">Actor Age</label>
      <input type="number" required="required" class="form-control" id="actorAge" placeholder="Actor Age" name ="age">
    </div>
  </div>
  
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/actor/index" role="button">Back to List</a>


  <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You don't need to add IDs on the form elements, they are already referable by their names and the FormData() automatically returns an array of these elements with their values

Comment: My problem is with using only the form elements is that when passing values through the url its better to use a random ID than to show you actual data

Comment: what is this  random ID technick ?

Comment: "_when passing values through the url_" You don't pass values through the url

Comment: fyi, the `for` attribute in labels should point to an `id` attribute on the associated form element

Comment: I solved this by adding a function in my traits folder. Thank you for the support.               `     public static function generateId(): string
    {
        return md5(date("Y-m-d H:i:sa"));
    }      `